# Android Preload TabHost View

Tags: android, view, fragment, android-tabhost, preload

Is it possible to pre-load all views in a TabHost containing fragments?

I have 3 screens A,B,C where C requires to generate a screenshot of A and B.
The thing is when I first load the view, view A is loaded and when I click on C, I get a NullPointerException in B because the view is not loaded. It only works if I click on B before clicking C.

Is there any way that I can pre-load all the views?
I tried using setCurrentTab(1) then setCurrentTab(0) but the onCreateView function is still not being called.

Any help is much appreciated...Thanks.

Comment: you need to post your code here.

Comment: if you use pageviewer , when the you are on A screen , at the same time B is loaded automatically

Answer (score 1):

if you use `pageviewer` , when the you are on A screen , at the same time B is loaded automatically 
And you can add `page indicator` and it is look like a `tabactivity` as well.
And you can do it with api level 8 to use support library, it is easy to implement

for page indicator link is :https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Is it not possible using TabHost?

Comment: why you do not want to use pageviewer?

Comment: I need the tabs to be at the bottom.

Comment: ok in the pageviewer it is possible too, you can use pageindicator for it

Comment: you can look this it is easy to implement https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Is it possible to have an icon on top of text in a tab at the bottom?

Comment: yes sure, you can look the github project there are more sample,you can put image and put it bottom and click to change tab , and it is also pageviewer so if you swipe screen it changes again,